# Pandas - duplicate rows based on values

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, pivot

I have a `dataframe`, where I want to duplicate rows N times, where N is a value in another row.

For example, if this is my dataframe:

```
   Company  WEEK_DAYS   SEPTEMBER 15    SEPTEMBER 22   SEPTEMBER 29    value      
0  google    MON-FRI         0                0              5          0.5
1  google       TUE          3                2              0          0.7
```

so, the columns I want to replicate based on their value are `SEPTEMBER 15`, `SEPTEMBER 22`, and `SEPTEMBER 29`, and the value should be `value`.

So the final output should be something like that:

```
     Company  WEEK_DAYS     WEEK       value
0    google    MON-FRI    SEPTEMBER 29  0.5
1    google    MON-FRI    SEPTEMBER 29  0.5
2    google    MON-FRI    SEPTEMBER 29  0.5
3    google    MON-FRI    SEPTEMBER 29  0.5
4    google    MON-FRI    SEPTEMBER 29  0.5   
5    google      TUE      SEPTEMBER 15  0.7 
6    google      TUE      SEPTEMBER 15  0.7 
7    google      TUE      SEPTEMBER 15  0.7
8    google      TUE      SEPTEMBER 22  0.7 
9    google      TUE      SEPTEMBER 22  0.7
```

I tried using `stack` and `pivot` - but I didn't manage to get the desired output.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

- first reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for `Series` with `Multiindex`
- [`repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.repeat.html) index for repeating all rows by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html)
- [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for convert `MultiIndex` to columns
- remove column `0` by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)
- rename column and change ordering by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

---

```
s = df.set_index(['Company','WEEK_DAYS','value']).stack()
df = (s.loc[s.index.repeat(s)]
       .reset_index()
       .drop(0, axis=1)
       .rename(columns={'level_3':'WEEK'})
       .reindex(columns=['Company','WEEK_DAYS','WEEK','value'])
      )
print (df)
  Company WEEK_DAYS          WEEK  value
0  google   MON-FRI  SEPTEMBER 29    0.5
1  google   MON-FRI  SEPTEMBER 29    0.5
2  google   MON-FRI  SEPTEMBER 29    0.5
3  google   MON-FRI  SEPTEMBER 29    0.5
4  google   MON-FRI  SEPTEMBER 29    0.5
5  google       TUE  SEPTEMBER 15    0.7
6  google       TUE  SEPTEMBER 15    0.7
7  google       TUE  SEPTEMBER 15    0.7
8  google       TUE  SEPTEMBER 22    0.7
9  google       TUE  SEPTEMBER 22    0.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `pandas.DataFrame.from_records` function.

I suggest you created a list of values you want to have in your new DataFrame, i.e

```
records = [('google', 'MON-FRI', 'SEPTEMBER 29', '0.5')]
# assumes only one record for MON-FRI .. you might need to do some handling here otherwise
records *= int(df['SEPTEMBER 29'][df[WEEK_DAYS] == 'MON-FRI'])
labels = ['Company', 'WEEK_DAYS', 'WEEK', 'value']

new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=labels)
```

I guess it's not the most elegant solution ever, but should work.